# Globalization only works on publish

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, format, globalization

I added `<globalization uiCulture="fi-FI" culture="fi-FI"/>` inside `<system.web>` ,`"Web.config"`, `"Web.Debug.config"` and `"Web.Release.config"`.

When I publish the site, `dates` are in correct format `d.m.yyyy`.
When I debug, `dates` are in wrong format `yyyy-mm-dd`.
What could possibly cause this?

Answer (score 3):

[Config transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx) in Visual Studio are only apply when you publish, as you have seen.

You can get them to apply during build using the [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) Visual Studio extension.

Comment: I had configured a special date format on Windows regional settings. That's why fi-FI actually became yyyy-mm-dd. Thanks for help anyway!